# C buffer issue hard coding

Tags: c

```
Rf_Rx_Buff[0];  //first 2 bits of serial number
Rf_Rx_Buff[1];  //second 2 bits
Rf_Rx_Buff[2];  //third
Rf_Rx_Buff[3];  //fourth
```

I want to hardcode the serial number of the device.

```
Rf_Rx_Buff[0]=0x30;
Rf_Rx_Buff[1]=0x67;
Rf_Rx_Buff[2]=0x43;
Rf_Rx_Buff[3]=0x57;
```

I am getting an error saying invalid dimension, missing basic type; int assumed

Comment: How is `Rf_Rx_Buff` declared?

Comment: It sounds like you never declared the array.

Comment: uchar Rf_Rx_Buff[4] = { 0x30, 0x67, 0x43, 0x57 };

Comment: Hold on a second: _"first 2 bits of serial number"_... What makes you say that `Rf_Rx_Buff[0]` is 2 bits? I've never seen an implementation where `unsigned char` was anything else than an 8bit integer type. You could use a `union` with an `uchar` and a bit-field struct, or just the bitfield struct, but there must be an easier way to do things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, you have to declare the type of the variable before you use it. And since you are using an array, you have to do it like this:

```
char Rf_Rx_Buff[4]; //declare an array of char with size 4
Rf_Rx_Buff[0]=0x30;
Rf_Rx_Buff[1]=0x67;
Rf_Rx_Buff[2]=0x43;
Rf_Rx_Buff[3]=0x57;
```